# C# createGraphics, pen only working initialized within panel paint event

Tags: c#

I need to draw random shapes with a random color and random position.
Now i figured out how to use a paint event but it only seems to work when I initialize then Pen within the paint event

```
    private void ShapesPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _graphics = ShapesPanel.CreateGraphics();
        _pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    }
```

This works, but I want the random colors and every shape has it own generated random color.

I have this foreach which works:

```
        foreach (var shape in _shapes)
        {
            shape.DrawAble(_graphics);
        }
```

Now I want to have the drawing to have to shapes color:

```
        foreach (var shape in _shapes)
        {
            _pen = new Pen(shape.Color, 3);
            shape.DrawAble(_graphics);
        }
```

And this will give no drawings at all.
Someone familiar?
Thanks

**form class**

```
    public partial class ShapesForm : Form
{
    private Shape _shape;

    private Graphics _graphics;
    private Pen _pen;

    private Random _random;

    private int _red, _blue, _green;
    private Color _color;

    private int _x, _y;
    private Point _point;

    private int _randomShape;

    private double _size;
    private double _radius;


    private List<Shape> _shapes;

    public ShapesForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _shapes = new List<Shape>();
        _random = new Random();
    }

    private void ShapesPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _graphics = ShapesPanel.CreateGraphics();
        _pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    }

    private void AddShapeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _red = _random.Next(0, 255);
        _green = _random.Next(0, 255);
        _blue = _random.Next(0, 255);
        _color = Color.FromArgb(1, _red, _green, _blue);

        _x = _random.Next(0, 100);
        _y = _random.Next(0, 100);
        _point = new Point(_x, _y);

        _radius = _random.Next(0, 20);
        _size = _random.Next(0, 20);

        _randomShape = _random.Next(0, 2);

        switch(_randomShape)
        {
            case 0:
                _shape = new Circle(_point, _color, _radius);
                _shapes.Add(_shape);
                UpdateShapeListBox();
                DrawShapes();
                break;
            case 1:
                _shape = new Square(_point, _color, _size);
                _shapes.Add(_shape);
                UpdateShapeListBox();
                DrawShapes();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateShapeListBox()
    {
        ShapesListBox.Items.Clear();

        foreach (var shape in _shapes)
        {
            ShapesListBox.Items.Add(shape.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void DrawShapes()
    {
        ShapesPanel.Refresh();
        foreach (var shape in _shapes)
        {
            _pen = new Pen(shape.Color, 3);
            shape.DrawAble(_graphics);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that.  You should never draw outside a `Paint` handler.

Comment: oke,, so how to solve?:P Still newby

Comment: And don't use `CreateGraphics()`. Use `e.Graphics`, and only inside the Paint handler (or methods that it calls).

Comment: Not sure how to call a event, but oke, going too google around!

Comment: Not sure what you want to so. You have a shapes collection. You want to loop over those and draw them with it's defined color? and a random position?

Comment: Yes thats quit right, Ill update the hole formclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of logic you want to implement:

```
private void ShapesPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var shape in _shapes)
    {
        shape.DrawAble(e.Graphics);
    }    
}

// in the Shape class
public void DrawAble(Graphics g)
{
    var pen = new Pen(this.Color, 3);
    g.DrawRect( ... ); // or whatever
}
```

You should use `e.Graphics` from the paint handler, and only while the paint handler is running.

The paint handler will normally be called whenever necessary. If you want to repaint because your shapes have changed, call `ShapesPanel.Invalidate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do all of your drawing in the `Paint` handler only, using `e.Graphics`.

If you want to draw something, call `Invalidate()` to raise a `Paint` event, then make sure your `Paint` handler will draw everything you want.